# No View shows when return to old page

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a layout with viewpager and fragments (say A, B, C, D).
In fragment A i have Tablayout where each Pages of tab is dynamically created

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    for (int i = 0; i < mergelist.size(); i++) {
        adapter.addFrag(new BlogFragmentContent(), mergelist.get(i).getNc_title(), mergelist.get(i).getNc_id());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

when i got to this layout for first Time it shows the view but if i go to any other Tab and return to this nothing shows.

Eg: First i clicked Fragment A (now view shows) then i go to Fragment C and return to Fragment A( no view there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    for (int i = 0; i < mergelist.size(); i++) {
        adapter.addFrag(new BlogFragmentContent(), mergelist.get(i).getNc_title(), mergelist.get(i).getNc_id());
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);  // put this line outside for loop
}
```

Try to set adapter after all pages added to it.

Comment: Thanks i think i should hav put that setAdapter outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Your fragment states of ViewPager are not retained as your are not passing proper fragment manager.

Use below for initializing your ViewPagerAdapter:

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

**EDIT:**
And yes shift setAdapter line outside of for loop